# Rendering shadows

Tags: rendering, shadows

When rendering scene the shadows render to a different layer. How do I combine them? Do I have to composite them together in an image editor?

Comment: How do you have your rendering passes set up? Are using the compositor? The default settings would normally give you the combined result...

Comment: The compositor doesn't seem to be combining the layers. I can find no setting to place the shadows on the combined layer.

Comment: Can you add some screen shots of your view layer settings, compositor nodes and what your results look like?

Comment: Thank you! For some reason the render started to combine...no idea why. But seems to be resolved. I truly appreciate your input!